# Command .ticket view does not display anything

Tags: azerothcore

`.ticket viewid 40` does not show anything INGAME

Same for other `.ticket list` commands

But they work fine in the console

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from an addon most likely.

For me, it was that old dirty addon "TrinityAdmin" (which should be remade correctly today).
Disable it or open it and go to the tab "Misc" and click on "Show chat output". Then click on "apply changes" and it should work